# Nodejs not returning promise properly

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm working on a NodeJS + Express + Mongoose + MongoDB project.

This code works fine:

```
var findRecord = function(id) {
  // find record by id
  return User.findOne({
    _id: id
  }).then(function(record) {
      // if record not found
      if (!record) {
        return Promise.reject(constant.NOT_FOUND);
      } else {
        // return found object
        return Promise.resolve({
            data: record,
            status: constant.READ_SUCCESS
        });
      }
    }, function() {
        // if there is error reading record
        return Promise.reject(constant.READ_ERROR);
    });
};
```

Don't know what is wrong with this one:

```
var allRecords = function(skip, limit) {
  // find all records
  return User.find({}).limit(limit).skip(skip)
    .then(function(records) {
        console.log('executed');
        // if records found
        return Promise.resolve({
            data: records,
            status: constant.READ_SUCCESS,
        });
    }, function() {
        return Promise.reject(constant.READ_ERROR);
    });
};
```

**executed** never prints on console

Even this one also don't work:

```
var allRecords = function(skip, limit) {
  // find all records
  return User.find({}).limit(limit).skip(skip)
    .exec(function(records) {
        console.log('executed');
        // if records found
        return Promise.resolve({
            data: records,
            status: constant.READ_SUCCESS,
        });
    }, function() {
        return Promise.reject(constant.READ_ERROR);
    });
};
```

Comment: Inside a callback to `.then` or `.catch`, instead of `return Promise.resolve(X)` do `return X`, and instead of `return Promise.reject(Y)` do `throw Y`. That's how promises are designed to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `exec` method:

```
User.find({}).limit(limit).skip(skip).exec();
```

Besides of this you shouldn't use `Promise.resolve` to return result from a promise, just return an object. Also, it's better to use `catch` callback, instead of second callback of `then`:

```
var allRecords = function(skip, limit) {
  return User.find({})
    .limit(limit)
    .skip(skip)
    .exec()
    .then(records => {
        console.log('executed');
        // if records found
        return {
            data: records,
            status: constant.READ_SUCCESS,
        };
    })
    .catch(err => Promise.reject(constant.READ_ERROR));
};
```

Comment: Thanks alexmac, you saved my day, this worked:
return User.find({}).limit(limit).skip(skip).exec().then(function(records) {

Comment: what does `constant.READ_ERROR` does? @Ashutosh

Comment: They are just constants having values 1-12